# QField edits are not being saved to the .gpkg file

Tags: qfield, qfieldsync

I am testing QField for use in the Field and it has worked well except for the synchronisation of the data back to QGIS.

I have followed the steps of multiple tutorials very closely and have had no success. When i load the Data back into QGIS with the plugin there are no error messaged, but the Features that were added in QField are not present, in the map or attribute table.

After some testing i found out that if i move the file dirtectory to a different place within the tablet all edited data is lost also. I am saving only in the internal storage.

Is there some "save" button i have overlooked?

I am using a windows 10 computer with QGIS 3.22.5. The devices were a Fairphone 3 and a lenovo tablet.

Comment: I found an answer! The problem was that in Qfield, when opening a project, i was not choosing the file directly (Through internal memory), but i was clicking on the three dots on the top right corner of the screen and choosing "import project from folder". This option creates a new file where the edits are saved. This file can also be accessed, but it is hidden deep in other folders. The ideal way to do it would be to choose the directory directly through "internal memory" and click on it, then it will be edited where it was to begin with. 2 days of frustration are finally solved!

Comment: Thanks @Zunchönig - this helped me.  I had copied a Qfield project to my phone's internal memory, then imported it from that location in QField.  I didnt realize QField copies the imported project to another location - in my case internal storage\Android\data\ch.opengis.field\files\imported Projects.

Comment: This is better explained in the [QField documentation on Storage Access](https://docs.qfield.org/get-started/storage/)

Comment: Thanks to both of you, @RobIrwin for providing the path, this helped me as well. You should make this into an answer that you can accept and one can upvote :)

Comment: WOW...thanks for posting this. This was not trivial. While it is in the docs (only found after this post)...when I say "open these files", I don't expect you to make a copy of them to some mysterious place then work with those files instead of the ones I asked you to open. Common QField!!!