# Added edits don't show or exist when loading project from QField back to QGIS

Tags: qgis, qfield

I have tried loading a map into QField on a tablet so I can draw fieldwork observations.
The map loads into QField perfectly fine and I can draw all I want. But when I load the project back onto QGIS on the computer, the project doesn't show the edits I made in the QField app. The attribute table on the project loaded on the computer also doesn't show that something new has been added.
I've tried manually transferring the documents, synching up with the cloud and exchanging the files there and everything I could think of.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Does this thread provide any help?  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/429201/qfield-edits-are-not-being-saved-to-the-gpkg-file

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have copied the project across by cable connection to your tablet, to a non-Qfield directory. In QField, you have then 'Imported' the project and worked on it.

Immporting, actually creates a copy of the project on your table in 'Internal Storage\Android\data\ch.opengis.qfield\files\Imported Projects'. This is the folder you need to copy back to your PC.

Also, see this article: https://www.opengis.ch/2022/03/05/qfield-users-sit-down-we-need-to-talk-about-storage-access-on-android%ef%bf%bc/